# Down-scoping Oauth access-token, possible?

Tags: javascript, oauth, authorization, gdata, access-token

I am developing an [open source javascript project](https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db). It has client side database, Oauth Connect login and bear-token base access to cross domain resource servers like (GData, Google cloud storage, AWS via proxy). The main focus is on consumer cloud data (you know, developer got free data storage).

The main goal to provide database to the web app without using backend server. It is achieved by keeping Oauth 2 refresh token in the server, providing access token to the web app so that it can populate its client side database, directly from resource servers. Dumb proxy server may be necessary for updating back to the resource server.

Login user may share his data to other login user. Server provides access token as necessary. In that case I wish to down-grade the access token. Generally once a new user start using the app, the server request off-line multiple scopes read-write grant. Currently, I as far I can understand a refresh token can generate access token of exact scopes.

Is that possible to request a down-graded access token from an offline refresh token? Even down grading from read-write to read-only is very useful.